# Lavaan: path analysis with ordered categorical (including binary) variables and missing data on endogenous variables

Tags: missing-data, categorical-data, r-lavaan

I have a case with missing data on endogenous variables and binary/ordinal endogenous variables.
The model 1 below represents it and it works perfectly. 
However, in the way it is written, it assumes that my variables are continuous (and they are actually all ordinal/binary) and it does not include the calculation of the indirect effects.
When I try to adjust it (as displayed in model 2) to consider these two things, it says the estimator FIML cannot be used with categorical data (so, it excludes all the lines with missing data). Furthermore, the resulting output doesn't even include standard deviations. 
Can anyone help me figuring out how to model that?
Thanks in advance

```
# Model 1
model1 <-'Importance~Seats+PriceRange
Measurement~Importance
Prekitchen~Importance+Measurement
Kitchen~Importance+Measurement
Postkitchen~Importance+Measurement
# Means are mentioned below so that all the information is used, bypassing listwise deletion
Seats~1
Price Range~1'
fit <- lavaan(model1, data=Mediate, missing="fiml")
summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
semPaths(fit)

# Model2
model2 <- 'Importance~Seats+PriceRange
# Including the paths to calculate the indirect effects
Measurement~a*Importance
Prekitchen~b*Measurement
Prekitchen~c*Importance
Kitchen~d*Measurement
Kitchen~e*Importance
Postkitchen~f*Measurement
Postkitchen~g*Importance
# Indirect effects exerted by Importance
ab:=a*b
total:=c+(a*b)
ad:=a*d
total:=e+(a*d)
af:=a*f
total:=g+(a*f)
Seats~1
Price Range~1'
# Including the variable type "Ordered" for all the categorical variables.
fit2 <- sem(model2, data=Mediate, missing="fiml", ordered=c("Importance", "Measurement", "Prekitchen", "Kitchen", "Postkitchen"))
summary(fit2, fit.measures=TRUE)
semPaths(fit2)
```

*P.S: I already used M-plus, but the problem in there is that for such a model, there are no goodness-of-fit indexes.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the Imputation before calculating your model? I think that would spare you the FIML chunk in your code.

I usually use the MICE package to do this:

`install.packages("mice")`

`library(mice)`

`md.pattern(data)`

If you want to take a closer look, here ist a usefull paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3074241/

Also, try using the function sem instead of lavaan and including the argument `ordered`, to indicate your data is categorical.

e. g.: `fit.1 <- sem(cat.1, data=data, std.lv=TRUE, ordered=names[1:n])`